# How do I count how many times someone has logged onto my system?

Tags: c#

I am building a basic atm and want to know how to count how many times someone has logged in.
I have a button which when I press I want it to display the amount of logins in the textbox next to it but I am unsure how I would count how many times someone logs in.

Any advice would be great thanks

I am using c#

Comment: when someone logs in, open a file, read the number of logins from the file, increase the number by one and save the number back to the file.

Comment: Start asking yourself: what happens when someone logs into my system? Where is the code that accepts the credentials and verify them?

Comment: the windows Event Viewer in "security", it logs all Login events ! :)

Comment: run admin: 
wevtutil qe security >%userprofile%\Desktop\log.txt

Answer (score 0):

In whatever data store that you are using to authenticate, you can also store how many times someone logged in. So you look up the user in a user table, and then update the user's row when the log on is successful.

If this is a learning-to-program sort of thing, you might not have a fancy datastore like a sql database, so you can use simple data stores.

The System.Data.DataSet can be saved to a file and behaves like a mini-database.  It's what I use when I'm writing throwaway code and I don't want to set up a sql database, but want more features than using System.IO to write to text files. (or raw xml files which have their own overhead, like having to write rather involved reading & parsing logic)